# How to animate UIView with a for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I would like to move a rectangle within a for loop to  create a random walk. But I only get the end position not motion in between. What do I have to do to see the individual steps?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController:UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class bird: UIView {
    var x:CGFloat
    var y:CGFloat

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func stepit(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat ){
        self.frame.origin.x += dx
        self.frame.origin.y += dy
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.960784316062927, green: 0.705882370471954, blue: 0.200000002980232, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let viewController = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let b=bird(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
viewController.view.addSubview(b)

for i in i... 100 {
   b.stepit(dx: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(10)), dy: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(10) ))
}
```

Comment: I see your all-caps, and raise you my downvote.

Comment: do some research, and also it's a good idea to follow naming conventions.

Comment: I'm not sure you are clearly understanding how the run loop cycle works in iOS...?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `animateWithDuration()`.  Place the following code in your `stepit()` function.  And as holex said, please do some research on the language.  A for loop does not pause at each step, you are moving the bird, however you're only seeing the ending point because it hits the for loop so fast.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in

    self.frame.origin.x = dx
    self.frame.origin.y = dy

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
})
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/